# Sympy - solve() and solve_poly_system()

Tags: python, solver, sympy

To begin with,

```
solve_poly_system( seq, *gens, **args),
```

does anyone know exactly what the arguments of solve_poly_system mean?

I have the system,

```
rd = λk
ua = λk
k = ad
```

where r, u, k are known and a,d, λ are variables.

When I use solve( system, [ a, d, λ]) I get the error,

```
NotImplementedError: only zero-dimensional systems supported (finite number of solutions)
```

This error is raised in the file

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/polysys.py", line 148, in solve_reduced_system
```

When I use solve_poly_system( system, [ a, d, λ]) everything is ok.

As I see, both solve() and solve_poly_system(), in the end, use the same function to solve the system. For non biquadratic, this same function is solve_generic( polys, opt) and then _solve_reduced_system(system, gens, entry=False)

Can anyone explain why this happening?

I want to use solve() because I am interested in only positive solutions and so I want to use the flag 'force'.

Comment: When you say "everything is ok", what solution do you get? Did you use the exclude flag? It seems like you equations should have precisely one solution.

Comment: "Everything is ok" = I take the right solution which is, λ = +-sqrt( ru / k), a = r / λ, d = u / λ with no complaint from python.

Comment: In the future, it will help a lot if you provide exact code that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

At first, after the recommendation of [Mateusz Paprocki](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/RyaP9tAqTeU), I installed sympy from [master](http://github.com/sympy/sympy). This solved the problem with solve()

After some effort, I discovered that my program was dependent from the order some input files were read. This caused both solve() and solve_poly_system() to exit with

```
NotImplementedError: only zero-dimensional systems supported (finite number of solutions)
```

when I changed the order of reading the input files.

To be more specific, I am working with Hadoop 1.0.2 Streaming . I am reading some files that each have a specific, different content and structure. This total content gives a linear system after some manipulation with sympy module. Here was the problem.

Hadoop Streaming doesn't read input files in any specific order. For this, you must be careful when you parsing different files together. My "parser" was expecting input files in a certain order. When the order was different, files' manipulation has been giving a wrong system to solve. For this reason, solve(), solve_poly_system() raised the NotImplementedError. The solution to this issue was to fix my "parser".

Finally, the arguments of solve_poly_system( seq, *gens, **args) from the way I used them, they mean

- seq = sequence, a sequence of equations that are equal to 0. In my
  case, the sequence was a list
- *gens = in my case, was a list of variables. According to these variables I solved my   system.

Comment: Which ways work, and which ways don't (if you could write down the solution which worked for you it could help other users sove this - excuse the pun) :)

Comment: You mean to write how to use solve() and solve_poly_system()?

Comment: Where you say "I discovered that my program was dependent from the order some input files were read", if you could elaborate with an example I think this would help explain solution.

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer (just click the checkbox under the vote arrows).